# VSTO Outlook: Customize email inspector header without using form regions

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

When you open an email by doing double click on it, I would like to know is the top panel of the email (header - indicate in the screenshot with a blue rectangle -) can be customized by adding text or other controls. Also in the context menu that appears when you click on the three dots button, I would like to know if I can add some options there. If that possible. Below I attach a screenshot and I indicate there the places where I would like to place these things (see blue arrows).

Also I would like to do the same in the preview area where the mail is shown when you select it from the messages list.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for customizing these bits. There is no trivial way to get the job done. The best what you could do is to develop a form region (Replacement or Replace-All) which can substitute the whole inspector UI, so you could re-build it from scratch. Read more about Outlook form regions in the [Walkthrough: Design an Outlook form region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-designing-an-outlook-form-region?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) article.

Also you may consider putting a form region with your custom information at the top of the window, but right below this pane. See [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions.php) from Add-in Express.

Comment: Yep, but the problem using a form region (replacement or replace-all) is that you then lose the default Outlook behavior (events on buttons, etc.) and you need to manage them by yourself.  Regarding Advanced Outlook view and form regions from Add-in Express is not free, you must pay.

Comment: One more thing, do you know some VSTO Outlook book you can recommend me? Also, apart from this forum, do you know other sites, forums where I can get more support. I see that there is not much support or information about VSTO Outlook. It seems that you and someone else are the only ones here who can help. Thanks for all your support beforehand, it's really helpful.

Comment: VSTO is a relatively old technology, so there are no books recently published on that. MSDN pages is the best source of knowledge for all MS technologies I think.